# putting all of your script calls in an include file

Tags: html

Is it good practice to put all of your script calls in an include file?

I have a design I am working on and utilzing some of the HTML5 boilerplate template, they have quite a few script calls at the bottom of the page...

I thought it would be better to put them all in one include file and reference them that way using absolute paths...

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

- use relative paths
- if the script isn't dynamic in anyway and is used on several pages then place it in an include file